# Google Dataflow inner join gives joins in a list [ ]

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using google data flow CoGbkResult to join two tables as inner join.

I was able to successfully join the table. 
I am writing the output to a text file and was able to verify the join. However the join puts the matching results in to a list.

Something like this.

```
301%103%203%2017-09-20 07:49:46[2%google, 3%google, 1%microsoft]
301%105%200%2017-09-17 11:48:59[2%google, 3%google, 1%microsoft]
```

`301%103%203%2017-09-20 07:49:46` is from table_1. `2%google`, `3%google`, `1%microsoft` are matching results for join in table_2.

Following is my `processElement` method:

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  KV<String, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
  String Ad_ID = e.getKey();
  Iterable<String> Ad_Info = null;
  Ad_Info = e.getValue().getAll(AdInfoTag);
  for (String ImpressionInfo : c.element().getValue().getAll(ImpressionInfoTag)) {
    // Generate a string that combines information from both collection values  
    c.output(KV.of(Ad_ID, "%" + ImpressionInfo + Ad_Info));
  }
}
```

I wonder how can I get the output in single row. For example:

```
301%103%203%2017-09-20 07:49:46 2%google
01%103%203%2017-09-20 07:49:46 3%google
01%103%203%2017-09-20 07:49:46 1%microsoft
301%105%200%2017-09-17 11:48:59 2%google 1%microsoft
301%105%200%2017-09-17 11:48:59 3%google
301%105%200%2017-09-17 11:48:59 1%microsoft
```

Comment: It's not completely clear how you want the output formatted. Specifically, in your example there are 3 different rows with the prefix "301%105%200%2017-09-17 11:48:59", and one of those rows has both "2%google" and "1%microsoft" on the line. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Ben Chambers... This is working when I do seperate parsing. Issue is cus I switched to the toString

Answer (score 1):

My understanding (partly guessing) about what you want to output is that you want to output a row for every entry in both the first and second iterable, but I'm not sure why you can't just use two for loops instead of converting the iterable to a string and then parsing it. For example:

```
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  KV<String, CoGbkResult> e = c.element();
  String Ad_ID = e.getKey();
  Iterable<String> Ad_Infos = e.getValue().getAll(AdInfoTag);
  for (String ImpressionInfo : c.element().getValue().getAll(ImpressionInfoTag)) {
    for (String Ad_Info : Ad_Infos) { 
      c.output(KV.of(Ad_ID, "%" + ImpressionInfo + Ad_Info));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this through a parser. 
Yet does GCP dataflow provide a method for this ?

int jointbegin = outputstring.indexOf("[");
                String firsthalf = outputstring.substring(0,jointbegin);
                String secondhalf = outputstring.substring(outputstring.indexOf("[") + 1, outputstring.indexOf("]"));

```
            if (!secondhalf.isEmpty())
            {
                String[] ad_data = secondhalf.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < ad_data.length; i++)
                {
                    String final_string = firsthalf + ad_data[i];
                    c.output(final_string);
                }
            }
          }
```

Comment: In the DoFn in your question, you (implicitly) called toString() on the iterable Ad_Info, and now you're parsing it back to extract individual components - why not just iterate over AdInfo in the original DoFn, which already contains the components?

Comment: Yeah, Ben's answer above describes exactly how to do this the right way.